# Automatically add new accounts to a user group in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

I want to set a default user group for new accounts created on a private MediaWiki installation.

So when I create an account it will automatically be added to the user group "The-User-Group-I-Specify".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by using the [LocalUserCreated hook](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/LocalUserCreated) in your `LocalSettings.php` file:

```
$wgHooks['LocalUserCreated'][] = function ( User $user, $autocreated ) {
    $user->addGroup( 'The-User-Group-I-Specify' );
};
```